# C# How to add elements to a specific index?

Tags: c#

I have a Class like this:

```
    internal class Name
    {
        public decimal A { get; set; }
        public decimal B { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Type
    {
        public string FullyName { get; set; }
        public List<Name> Name{ get; set; }
        public Type()
        {
            Name = new List<Name>();
        }
    }
```

I can add new Elements to List like this:

```
    internal static List<Type> test = new List<Type>();

                    var pl = new Type{ Name = "test" };
                    pl.Name.Add(new Name { A = 0, B = 1 });
                    test.Add(pl);
```

But how can I add only new Decimals ("under Name") at a specific index and not to new rows at FullyName? So I want new rows under Names and not new rows under FullyName

I tryed with this, but it is not working

```
test.Insert(index, 0, 1);
```

I mean this: (adding new items/elements under "Name" in a specific index FullyName: XY Collection)

```
  FullyName: XY
    [0] > Name:
          [0] > decimal A: 0
          [1] > decimal B: 1
          [2]... and so on
  FullyName: ZA
    [1] > Name:
          [0] > decimal A: 0
          [1] > decimal B: 1
          [2] > decimal A: 3
          [3] > decimal B: 4
          [4]... and so on
```

-So, if i Search with Linq the Index of the FullyName XY the Answer is 0: So then i must add new Items/Elements (decimal A / decimal b) under FullyName: XY with the Index of 0 (then under Name adding new Items/Elements), but this is not working with my code for adding new FullyNames or Insert :/

-Hope now is Clearly what i mean :)
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the index of which `FullyName` list you want to add decimals to. You seem to be able to do this with LINQ already. Let's say you store this index in a variable called `index`.

Now, `test[index]` will give you a `Type` object, so `test[index].Name` will give you a `List<Name>`, which you can add, insert, remove (or do whatever) pairs of decimals (they're actually `Name` objects).

To add `{ A = 0, B = 0 }` at to the `FullyName` list at index `index`, you do:

```
test[index].Name.Add(new Name { A = 0, B = 0 });
```

I think your confusion comes from the naming of your members. You should definitely give better names to them. Maybe:

```
internal class DecimalPair
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal B { get; set; }
}

internal class DecimalPairs
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<DecimalPair> Decimals{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thx @Sweeper This > test[index].Name.Add(new Name { A = 0, B = 0 }); < Its what i needed :) Yes, i must give the Classes Better Names, its a little bit Confusing :(